# Jenkins pipeline not executing pipe | multiple commands

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to execute multiple commands using pipe (|) but somehow its not working.

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {

      stage('Build') {

         steps {
                sh label: '', script: ''' 
                                            cd $WORKSPACE/dist
                                            "ls | grep -i main-es2015 | xargs -I '{}' javascript-obfuscator '{}' --compact true"
                                            "ls | grep -i main-es2015 | xargs mv $1 $2"
                                      '''


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JobName@tmp/durable-99f8a65e/script.sh: 7: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JobName@tmp/durable-99f8a65e/script.sh: ls | grep -i main-es2015 | xargs -I '{}' javascript-obfuscator '{}' --compact true: not found
```

Comment: Why do you quote these lines?

Comment: it allows to run single command while using pipe with multiple commands.

Comment: I think @tkausl is correct, you should remove the double quotation marks from the commands.

Comment: I tried without double quotation too but its execute individual command after | pipe

Comment: @tkausl and zett42 Thanks for commenting. its working after removing quotes.